# Git reset --soft head after Git stash - how can I get my most recently committed code

Tags: git

I did:

```
git stash
```

then:

```
git reset --soft head
```

And I'm not exactly sure what git reset --soft head has achieved. My understanding is that it should reset my local database back to the last commit, which almost sounds like nothing is actually happening. I'm not sure how I can see what HEAD is now pointing to. How do I find this?

What I'm trying to do is get my latest commit into my workspace then un-stash my changes to pull them back. What do I do next?

Comment: run `git reflog` and you will see what you have done

Comment: From what I expect, if you did a `git stash` then you should already be sitting on the latest commit on the current branch.  So the `git reset` may have been unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Martin and Tim that helps me, although I can now see that I'm at HEAD@{0} and no clearer, as this reinforces to me that head is at my last commit, so it's like nothing really happened. Make your comments answers if you want and I'll give you both an upvote

Answer (score 2):

when you do

```
git stash
```

you put all your **staged** and **unstaged** changes in a stash. After that you will be on your last commit, without additional changes (except for **untracked** changes which remain). `git reset` is no longer necessary then.

Suppose you want to get the changes you **stashed** back, then you can do:

```
git stash apply
```

which applies the latest stash, but that stash remains in the list. If you do

```
git stash pop
```

and the stash is successfully applied; it will be removed from the stash list (which you can view using `git stash list`)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'm still a little nervous on what I need to do to pull the commit into my workspace, because I still have my stashed changes showing in the workspace - I want my workspace to show the commit that head is pointing to. Add another answer with help for this and I'll upvote you again :)

Comment: normally if you do `git stash` you shouldn't see your changes anymore, so something is not normal there... as I said in my answer: you should see only the untracked files